# Openshift 3.11 atomic-openshift-node - Service Restart Impact

Tags: openshift

We have a plan to scaleup the Max Pod Per node from 200 to 350.
Based on the documentation - in order for the new node config to take effect the atomic-openshift-node service needs to be restarted.

This cluster where the node is located, served business critical DCs, PODS, services, routes etc.

The question is, what are the possible operational impact during the restart of the atomic service if any? Or is it totally no direct impact to the applications?

Ref: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.3/install_config/master_node_configuration.html

Comment: Hi, In my experience, there is no impact on running containers on that node, when you restart atomic-openshift-node service.  frequently, i needed to restart this service in order to remove stale state of volumes on node.  However, if you restart docker, then all of the containers have impact.

Comment: Thanks @SureshVishnoi I executed the atomic node service restart - no impact as mentioned.

Comment: @ Edcel Cabera Vista no problem !!

Answer (score 1):

Containers should run fine without interruption. But nodeservice (node controller) in some cases can send "NotReady" status for some PODs. I dont know what is the cause. I suspect a race condition, guessing the dependence on the time of restart and  readiness probe parameters, maybe on other node performance conditions.
This *may* result in the service being unavailable for a while if it will be removed from the "router" backends.
Most likely, in case only one node is changed at time and important applications are well scaled with HA rules in mind, there should be no "business impact".
But, in case of node control configmap change (3.11, new design introduced long after the original question), possible many node controllers are restarted in parallel (in fact, it does not happen immediately, but still within a short period), which I consider as problematic consequence of node controll configmap concept (one for all appnodes).